# Restricting sonarqube access only via Apache Reverse proxy server

Tags: apache, sonarqube, reverse-proxy, sonarqube-ops

I have configured my Sonarqube server to be accessed using the reverse proxy mechanism provided by Apache server mod_proxy module.

My question here is, even after the above setup i will be able to access the sonarqube server by hitting the direct sonarqube url ex:http://localhost:9000.

Is there a way i can restrict the access to my sonarqube server only via Apache reverse proxy server, by making simple configuration changes may be in some sonarqube property files.

Or Any other solution for this requirement?

I am using the latest version of Sonarqube 6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ragdu you have to bind SonarQube to localhost. In sonar.properties use  : `sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1`

Obviously you will be able to browse from your server by accessing http://localhost:9000 but only from your server, you won't be able to access through http://{your_server_ip}:9000.

Comment: @ehartmann,  Now we have the requirement to host Apache and Sonarqube on two different boxes.
Any suggestions or ideas regarding this would be most welcome.

Comment: @Raghu, it depends on the security you have between your users and the servers, if everything is open the best way if everything is unsecured is to add an httpd server (and only allowing connections from your Apache server)

Answer (score 0):

Binding the server to localhost is the correct option, but if for some reason you don't want to touch sonar.properties, or you need to switch to the 'two different boxes approach' you can use the system firewall to filter the access.

In the first case, you drop all packets coming from your network card to port 9000 (but you need to allow the access in the local interface).

In the second one you would only allow the Apache machine's IP to communicate with the port 9000 in the SonarQube machine, all other packets coming to port 9000 would be discarded.

Be careful, in the second case you should implement SSL between Apache and SonarQube or isolate both machines, otherwise the HTTP communication could be sniffed.